# Google app engine delete entity free memory

Tags: google-app-engine

How do i delete the whole table (entity) thereby freeing all the memory in google app engine where the entity is defined as follows:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    message=db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created=db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am working in python...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
db.delete(Message.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (especially if you're model has a large number of entities) is to go to the 'Datastore Admin' tab of the app engine console. Here you can select a kind and choose to delete all entities (app engine starts a mapreduce job to delete all the entities).

This is useful when you have enough entities that doing

```
db.delete(Message.all())
```

will timeout/take way too long.